# Getting error "startup failed: General error during class generation: Method code too large!"

Tags: java, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

We are currently using scripted pipeline and I want to continue to further stages even if the build fails in particular stage.

My current script

```
 stage('Push')
    {
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'gitlogin', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME')]) {
            //sh("git tag -a some_tag -m 'Jenkins'")
                sh('git push --tags origin $BRANCH_NAME')
            }
            if ("${BRANCH_NAME}"=="develop" || ("${BRANCH_NAME}".startsWith("release")))
            {    
                sshagent (credentials: ['GitSSHLOGIN']) {
//                    sh("git tag -d PSTEST ")
                    sh("git tag -a PBCS_${BRANCH_NAME}_${ReleaseNumber}_${BUILD_NUMBER} -m 'Tag the build PBCS_${BRANCH_NAME}_${ReleaseNumber}_${BUILD_NUMBER}'")
                    sh('git push --tags origin $BRANCH_NAME')
                }
            }
    }
```

I am trying below line

```
            catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE')
```

But jenkins is throwing error

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during class generation: Method code too large!

java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!
```

I request if someone can help me to restructure this code to fix the issue.

Comment: Did you see: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37984, having the same issue now, there is no fix, only restructuring your pipeline